# How to update Process Instance Step

Tags: approval-process, approval-step

I have an record with the object,The Record has already entered into the approval process with the step, After some days I have cloned the same approval process and recreated with the different type of users with the same step.But now the step is not updated to the record.It is Pointing to the old Process definitionId.How to update the ProcessInstance step for the particular Record?.Can anyone help to guide me the update way of approach to the approval process for ProcessInstancestep of particular record?

> How to update processInstance step for particular record:?

Comment: Have you deactivated old approval process?